# Personal notebooks of a Fields medalist

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I once read that some Fields medalist published all of his personal handwritten notebooks, and that they are freely available somewhere on the net.

I can't remember whose mathematician it was, so I can't find the notes anymore. Do someone knows who it is and where to find the notes?

I remember browsing the notes, I find it quite fascinating that we can follow a little bit his flow of thought. I think it is of great pedagogical value.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of Villani, [Theoreme Vivante](http://www.amazon.com/Birth-Theorem-Mathematical-C%C3%A9dric-Villani-ebook/dp/B00NS3174O/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1460637488&sr=1-1&keywords=villani)

Comment: @lulu No. It was his personal hand-written notes over almost his entire career. In several pdfs photocopied directly from his notebooks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Daniel Quillen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Quillen) (Fields Medal 1978).

[Here](http://www.claymath.org/publications/quillen-notebooks) is the link to his notebooks.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! :-)